# Display of text in NSTextField from a timer

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am using

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: _callbackPeriod
                                 target: self
                               selector: @selector(timerCallback:)
                               userInfo: nil
                                repeats: NO];
```

to time an interval. This interval may vary, but I am testing it at 1 second. At the end of every interval (1 second) a simple UI text box is updated and then the timer is scheduled again. The update is invoked via

```
NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:named 
                                                             object:info];
[notificationCenter postNotification:notification];
```

the notification code performs

```
NSString* timerString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", info.timerCount];
[_timerValue setStringValue:timerString];
```

where

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *timerValue;
```

This method will display a running counter that gets incremented whenever the interval ends.

The problem I am having is that the display of the data is slow. I should see a smooth display of the interval as it progresses but instead it is choppy.  NSLogs show that indeed the data is smooth but the display is not.  So instead of displaying 1,2,3,4 5, etc., I am seeing 1,3, 4, 6,...  Any idea what I am doing wrong? Is there some sugar I need around setStringValue?

Thanks.

Comment: What is _callbackPeriod?  Never mind...  I guess it's the number of seconds.  If the reapts BOOl option is set to NO, how does timerCallback gets called repeatedly?

Comment: When the timer goes off, updates are published then the timer is scheduled again.

Comment: NSLog in update shows all values for the counter 1,2,3,4... but the display jumps values: 1,3,4,6...  Apparently the update is getting overwritten by the next  before it can be displayed.

Comment: _callbackPeriod = 1.0;

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a countdown timer, should help you out.

```
- (void)startCountdown {
    countdownSeconds = 60; 
    startTime = [NSDate date];

    countdown = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self
    selector:@selector(countdownUpdateMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    // invalidate the timer if the view unloads before the end
    // also release the NSDate if it does not reach the end
}

- (void)countdownUpdateMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer {

    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval elaspedTime = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];

    NSTimeInterval difference = countdownSeconds - elaspedTime;
    if (difference <= 0) {
        [theTimer invalidate];  // kill the timer
        difference = 0;
    }

    // Update the label with the remaining seconds
    NSString *countdownString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",difference];

    countdownLabel.text = [countdownString substringToIndex:2];
   // NSLog(@"%f",difference);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The timer works but the display doesn't reliably update. Any insight?

Comment: So I used Kenrik's idea and it works. The display is now smooth. I modified it so that it doesn't repeat, and changed the period from .1 to 1. The key between the way I did and it and Kenrik's way is the tracking of the difference between elapsed time and interval period. I noticed that there were triggers that occurred that didn't line up with the 1 second interval in my technique. This caused the flashing. The NSTimer mechanism is 'unique' I suppose. Thanks for the help.